# Trouble with javascript variables in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am having some trouble with variables in javascript and asp.net mvc project.

I am building an app where the user has the option to display a page in full-screen format.

When the user wants to display a page in full screen format and click the submit key they should get a warning before the page is submitted.

I am having some problems with the javascript that handles the condition if the user should get a warning or not however. 
 The following code illustrates the problem:

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var $full = false; //initiates the full variable

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TemplateID").change(function () { //when selected index of dropdown is changed
            var selectedIndex = $("select option:selected").first().text(); //the selected index
            $.get('@Url.Action("getIfFullscreen", "Messages")', //calls an ASP.net method to determine if selected index should be displayed as fullscreen
                { id: selectedIndex }, function (data) {
                    $full = data; //sets the variable full to return value
                    Debug.writeln("onchange:" + $full) //displays as expected
                });
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-confirm]').click(function (e) {
            Debug.writeln("onclick:" + $full); //displays as expected
            if ($full == true){ //always takes the value from when the variable full was initiated
                if (!confirm($(this).attr("data-confirm"))) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" data-confirm="Are you sure?" value="Skicka" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

It seems like the variable *full* is changed (in the first function) from the look of the debug output but the if statement always interprets it as it was first initiated.

I am quite new to javascript and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value you see in `$full` ? Are you setting it to boolean true or a string "true" ?

Comment: I am setting it with boolean true/false from the asp.net part. I think you have pointed me in the right direction. I changed the full - variable to use integers instead and now it seems to work when i use 0 and 1 instead of true and false. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yea. I added an answer explaining why it could be failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server code is returning a boolean true value, It will come as `True`, not `true`. **In javascript `True` is not boolean `true`**. So your js variable is going to be overwritten with the string value `"True"`

So you may change your if condition to check against the string value

```
if ($full === "True"){  }
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!